# Human normal EEG Relative Power Spectra during Rest

Tags: data-request

Where can I find a open dataset of an adult man healthy/normal EEG Relative Power Spectra Density during rest?
Like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272147753_Mathematical_Modeling_of_Human_Brain_Neuronal_Activity_in_the_Absence_of_External_Stimuli), but in a Relative PSD (%) How to convert "Fourier amplitude a.u." into Relative PSD (%)?
[image: Human normal EEG power spectra during rest]